# Click and show?

Tags: javascript

I am working with this:

```html
<html>
<ol onclick="myevent(event);">
  <li title="a">Test 1</p>
    <li title="b">Test 2</p>
</ol>
<div id="a" style="display:none;">Text to show</div>
<div id="b" style="display:none;">Other text to show</div>

<script>
  function myevent(event) {

    var x, i, clk, res;
    x = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    clk = event.target.title;
    res = document.getElementById(clk);

    res.style.display = "block";

  }
</script>

</html>
```

Essentially click one line item, hide all blocks, and then show the named block.  This should be simple but I have been researching for hours and getting nowhere.

Thanks in advance!
- Joe

Comment: have you checked if the event is emitted when you click, you can check that by applying `console log` or `debugger` in your script or function

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos in your code.

Firstly, you are wrongly closing `li` element with `</p>`

Secondly,  `getElementsBytagname` should be [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and `getelementbyid` should be [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```js
function myevent(event){

  var x, i, clk, res;
  x = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  clk = event.target.title;
  res = document.getElementById(clk);

  res.style.display="block";

}
```

```html
<ol onclick="myevent(event);">
  <li title="a">Test 1</li>
  <li title="b">Test 2</li>
</ol>
<div id="a" style="display:none;">Text to show</div>
<div id="b" style="display:none;">Other text to show</div>
```

You can also try using [**`querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [**`forEach()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) that does not require the loop variable `i`:

```js
function myevent(e){

  var x, clk, res;
  x = document.querySelectorAll("DIV");
  x.forEach(div => div.style.display = "none");  
  clk = e.target.title;
  res = document.getElementById(clk);

  res.style.display="block";

}
```

```html
<ol onclick="myevent(event);">
  <li title="a">Test 1</li>
  <li title="b">Test 2</li>
</ol>
<div id="a" style="display:none;">Text to show</div>
<div id="b" style="display:none;">Other text to show</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. Was not a typo. I just forgot to change the close tags when switching the element. The "foreach" and querySelectorAll is a good idea, but it was the next portion I was having the issue. This part:  clk = e.target.title;
  res = document.getElementById(clk); res.style.display="block";  is what did not work. Please advise

Comment: @TheCrazyTech, but the code snippet in my solution seems work accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

#### Event Handlers

There's three ways to handle an event (in this case the click event on `<ol>`):

- Event Attribute (not recommended)

  ```
  <ol onclick="eventHandler(); return false">...</ol>
  ```
- Event Property

  ```
  document.querySelector('ol').onclick = eventHandler;
  ```
- Event Listener (recommended)

  ```
  document.querySelector('ol').addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
  ```

For details refer to [Introduction to Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) and [DOM Onevent Handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)

---

#### Event Delegation

The following demo uses a programming paradigm called *Event Delegation*. The advantages over the code provided in **[OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60664389/2813224)** (**O**riginal **P**ost) are:

- Only one tag needs to be registered as the event listener (common ancestor tag of all targeted tags - ex. `<ol>` is an ancestor tag to all `<li>`).
- There's no need to loop thru each targeted tag and register each one to an event (ex. `<li>` do not have to be in a `for` loop).
- There can be an unlimited number of targeted tags and knowing how many is not required. (ex. there can be a single `<li>` to theoretically thousands of `<li>`).
- The targeted tags can be added dynamically anytime -- during or after page load. If done any other way, any dynamically added tags would not work without reloading the page and somehow keeping them.

Refer to [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) for details.

---

#### References

In the following demo these methods and properties were used:

**DOM**

- **[Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**
- **[Element.tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)**
- **[Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)**

**Event**

- **[EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**
- **[Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)**
- **[Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)**
- **[Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)**

---

#### Demo

**Details are commented in demo**

```js
/* EVENT DELEGATION */
// Register Ancestor Tag to Event
/*
Register the click event to a common ancestor tag of all 
tags you want to be clickable.
So in this instance the clickable tags are all <li>
Ancestor tags could be:
  window
  document
  <body>
  <main>
  <ol>
Usually the closest tag is the best choice which is <ol>
*/
// ------ Breakdown ------
/* 
  document.querySelector('ol') 
  -- find <ol>

  .addEventListener('click'... 
  -- register click event to <ol>

  ..., eventHandler); 
  -- run function eventHandler() when <ol> is clicked
*/
document.querySelector('ol').addEventListener('click', eventHandler);

// Event Object
/* 
Pass event object which will have properties and methods that will allow us to:
  1. find what tag is listening for click event
    - event.currentTarget
    - in this demo it is <ol>
  2. find what tag the user actually clicked
    - event.target
    - in this demo only <li> will react to being clicked
  3. stop the click event from "bubbling" up the event chain
    - event.stopPropagation();
    - this method is called at the end of eventHandler() so
      that the click event doesn't trigger anything else
*/
function eventHandler(event) {
  // Reference all tags concerned
  // See Event Object #1
  const listener = event.currentTarget;
  // See Event Object #2
  const clicked = event.target;
  // Find <output>
  const display = document.querySelector('output');

  // ------ Breakdown ------
  /*
  if <ol> isn't the tag that the user clicked...
  ... and if the clicked tag is a <li>...
  ... get the text inside that <li>...
  ... and place it in <output> 
  (it gets overwritten on each click so there's no need for multiple tags)
  */
  if (listener !== clicked) {
    if (clicked.tagName === 'LI') {
      let data = clicked.textContent;
      display.textContent = data;
    }
  }
  /*  
  Regardless of whether any <li> were clicked stop the click event
  See Event Object #3
  */
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
main {
  font: 700 1rem/1.5 Tahoma
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<main>
  <ol>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
  </ol>
  Item: <output></output>
</main>
```